# Is character of a group representation the same as trace?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

If so, why cannot the Klein group's character be zero? The group element of Klein group matrices can be traceless, right?

Comment: A character of a group is the trace of a representation of that group, seen as a map from the set of conjugacy classes of the group to the complex numbers. Group element do not themselves have traces (unless we pick a faithful representation).

Comment: The matrix representing a single element of the group can, indeed, have trace zero. The trace of the neutral element, however, is equal to the dimension of the representation. The character is a function from the group to complex numbers, or a vector in the space of such functions, so it is not zero unless it is zero for all elements of the group.